# PowerShellでCSVから読み込んだ各要素を加工し、CSVで出力

Tags: powershell

CSVファイルを読み込み、半角スペースを消して出力したいと考えています。

**元データ:**

```
1111     ,test2    ,test3   ,test4    
111     ,test2    ,test3   ,test4    
11     ,test2    ,test3   ,test4
```

**期待する結果:**

```
1111,test2,test3,test4
111,test2,test3,test4
11,test2,test3,test4
```

CSVの各要素の半角スペースをTrimするため、PowerShellで次のようなコードを書いたのですが、出力されたCSVが`$results`のlengthになってしまいます。

解決策等ないでしょうか。

```
$clms =@("col1","col2","col3","col4");

$products = Import-Csv 'C:\test\input.csv' -Header $clms -Encoding Default
$results = @()

foreach ($product in $products){
 $line  = @()
    foreach ($clm in $clms) {
        $line += $product.$clm.Trim()
    }
 $results += $line
}

$results | Export-Csv -Encoding Default -NoTypeInformation 'C:\test\output.csv'
```

Comment: 何か合わない条件があるかもしれませんが、こんな記事が参考になるかもしれません。[Powershell Remove spaces in the header only of a csv](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53885497/9014308)

Answer (score 0):

読み込んだデータを変更して保存すれば良いと思います。

```
$clms =@("col1","col2","col3","col4");

$products = Import-Csv 'input.csv' -Header $clms -Encoding Default
$results = @()

foreach ($product in $products){
  foreach ($clm in $clms) {
    $product.$clm= $product.$clm.Trim()
  }
}

$products | Export-Csv -Encoding Default -NoTypeInformation 'output.csv'
```

input.csv

> 1111 ,test2 ,test3 ,test4
> 111 ,test2 ,test3 ,test4
> 11 ,test2 ,test3 ,test4

output.csv

> "col1","col2","col3","col4"
> "1111","test2","test3","test4"
> "111","test2","test3","test4"
> "11","test2","test3","test4"

Answer (score 0):

「出力されたCSVが`$results`のlengthになってしまいます。」についてはこちらの記事が関連するようですね。
`Export-Csv`が出力する対象のデータが違うようです。
[Export-CSV exports length but not name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19450616/9014308)

> `Export-Csv` exports a table of object properties and their values. Since your script is producing string objects, and the only property they have is length, that's what you got.
>
> If you just want to save the list, use `Out-File` or `Set-Content` instead of `Export-Csv`.

> Export-Csvは、オブジェクトのプロパティとその値のテーブルをエクスポートします。 スクリプトは文字列オブジェクトを生成しており、それらが持つ唯一のプロパティは長さであるため、それが得られます。
>
> リストを保存するだけの場合は、Export-Csvの代わりにOut-FileまたはSet-Contentを使用します。

それから、`$line += $product.$clm.Trim()`や`$results += $line`の処理だと1行の中の各列のデータが分離されてそれぞれ1行のデータに分かれてしまいます。
`$results += $line`の際に[about_Join](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_join?view=powershell-7.2)でカンマで連結しておく必要があるでしょう。

対策としては以下のように2行を変更します。`####`でコメントした部分が変更点です。

```
$clms =@("col1","col2","col3","col4");

$products = Import-Csv 'C:\test\input.csv' -Header $clms -Encoding Default
$results = @()

foreach ($product in $products){
 $line  = @()
    foreach ($clm in $clms) {
        $line += $product.$clm.Trim()
    }
 $results += $line -join ',' #### 接続しておかないとすべてが各行に分かれて格納される
}

$results | Out-File -Encoding Default 'C:\test\output.csv' #### Export-CsvではなくOut-File
```

Answer (score 0):

CSVとして扱う必要があるのか気になりました。単なるテキストファイルとして扱い、`,`の前の空白の削除ではダメですか？

```
Get-Content C:\test\input.csv -Encoding Default |
  ForEach-Object { $_ -replace ' ,', ',' } |
  Set-Content C:\test\output.csv -Encoding Default
```